Prevent Vite/RollUp from scoping globalThis
I'm using PDF.js and one of its classes is instantiated with:
class DOMCanvasFactory extends _base_factory_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.BaseCanvasFactory {
  constructor({
    ownerDocument = globalThis.document
  } = {}) {
    super();
    this._document = ownerDocument;
  }
  _createCanvas(width, height) {
    const canvas = this._document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    return canvas;
  }
}

The issue is when this code is bundled with Vite/Rollup then globalThis.document is undefined. If I hard code globalThis.document = window.document then this works, but only in development. Once this is built for production the globalThis becomes a local var within PDF.js and again its document value is undefined.
  constructor({ ownerDocument: N = hn.document }={}) {
    super();
    this._document = N;
  }

  _createCanvas(N,V) {
    const ie = this._document.createElement("canvas");
    return ie.width=N,ie.height=V,ie
  }

hn is the scoped version of globalThis we have in development and document is undefined.
Is there a way within Rollup/Vite to stop it converting the globalThis?
